# Generating a new variable in R foreach

Tags: r, foreach

Cheers,

I have an index for anxiety with repeated measures.
Say I want to compute anxiety1=mood1+tension1+fears1 but I want to compute anxiety1-anxiety9 and have mood1-mood9 etc etc. Is there a way to do this in R or must I type this manually?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example so that others may help you.

Comment: Please provide a small, reproducible example of your problem.